# how update local aar package sources

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I created two Android Studio applications. One of them is aar library. I used this aar library in second application. I added aar library by using File->New->New Module->Import AAR/JAR Packages option. after that I can see decompiled sources of my aar library. When I update aar library I copy and paste new aar file to my application project folder. But this time Android Studio shows older decompiled sources. But compile new source successfully. How can I update decompiled sources in Android Studio ? when I import aar file `implementation project(':app-debug')` line was added my `build.gradle` file.

I am using Android Studio 3.0.1

**my solution**

the only way I can find to update local sources is clicking **Sync Project with Gradle Files** button after updating aar/jar file.

Comment: Do the old and new aar files have the same version or are they different versions?

Comment: do you mean versionCode in build.gradle ?. I did not change it.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. If you change the versionCode Android Studio should check more thoroughly for the sources.

Comment: @Cliabhach, I tried that. but situation is same.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe if you try the `Invalidate Caches` command? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html?origin=old_help

Comment: unfortunately it is not work. situation is same.

Comment: Ugh. This is weird. Um....the aar file should be referenced in your application's build.gradle file. It should look like `implementation files("my_cool_library.aar")` or `implementation "com.example.projects:cool_library:1.1"` Does that exist? You can add it to the question if it does.

Comment: @Cliabhach, I updated my question

Answer (score 62):

I was having the same issue, had tried every form of including my local aar in my project, tried every method of rebuilding, invalidating caches etc, but I was still having the problem where changes in my local aar were not available after updating the file in the libs folder.

The only thing that worked for me was this:

1. Comment out the implementation files('../libs/yourlib.aar') line in gradle
2. Sync gradle
3. Update yourlib.aar in the libs folder
4. Uncomment the implementation files('../libs/yourlib.aar') line in gradle
5. Sync again
6. Build project

Now the changes in yourlib.aar should be available in your project. If you have this lib included in multiple modules I am guessing you'll have to do it for each module. Not ideal, but I spent at least 5 hours on this issue and these steps were the only way I could seemingly force the changes. I am guessing that removing the library from the gradle file and then syncing will force it to pick up the new one when it is added again.

Comment: this worked for me, just want to mention that it is important to change the file only after the first gradle sync

Comment: Invalidating caches happened to work for me, just in case that also helps anyone else out.

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue and solved it very quickly doing the following:

- Look in your project /.idea/libraries/ folder for Gradle__artifacts_[subproject].xml
- Delete this file
- In Android Studio, go to File->Sync Project with Gradle Files

This is for an AAR included as a project (which is how it is included when you use File->New->New Module...->Import .JAR/.AAR Package).

Comment: Thanks your answer, which saves my day.

Comment: Thats the only valid solution which actually could be implemented in the CI without  updating library version. Should be marked as accepted answered and Android Studio development team should fix this years ago.

Comment: It's useful - but do you not still have to manually copy the .aar files from the Library project to the project actually using the library?

Answer (score 5):

Right now you're including the AAR through a `project` notation. Since an AAR is literally just a file, it should be included with the `files` notation instead.

Assuming a folder structure like so:

[image: screenshot of the folder directory of a new Android Studio 3 project]

You could include the files with any of the following lines in the dependencies block of `app/build.gradle`:

```
  // include just my_library
  implementation files('libs/my_library.aar')

  // include just other_library
  implementation files("$rootDir/common/libs/other_library.aar")

  // include both libraries
  implementation files('libs/my_library.aar', "$rootDir/common/libs/other_library.aar")
```

By the way, there's a reasonably complete list of supported dependency types at https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html .

Answer (score 3):

After replacing .arr file through Windows explorer. The only thing that worked for me is File -> Invalidate caches / Restrt

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried closing the tab of your decompiled file on Android Studio first, update the versionName on the AAR project, rebuild AAR, transfer, and then see it gets updated?

I know it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Commenting/Uncommenting & Re-sync Gradle project and settings,
I had to delete the entire build-cache directory.

On Mac: ~/.android/build-cache/
Windows: Unsure of where this directory location is.